# Слообразовательная цепочка со словом "штриховать"

Tags: словообразование

На школьной олимпиаде было дано задание: *восстановите недостающие звенья в словообразовательной цепочке … - ШТРИХОВАТЬ - ШТРИХОВКА.*
Первым делом в голову приходит ответ: "штрих". Но не слишком ли это простой вариант для олимпиады? В словаре Тихонова эту цепочку не нашла.

Answer (score 3):

Штрих (1 элемент) - штриховой (содержащий группу штрихов - узор, код) - штрихованный (подвергнутый действию нанесения группы штрихов - участок поверхности или изображения) - штриховать (действие по нанесению) - штриховка (процесс или результат действия).

Comment: _Alex_ander: ...штрихованный (**подвергнутый действию** нанесения группы штрихов - участок поверхности или изображения) - штриховать (**действие** по нанесению)..._ === Ну так сначала-то должно идти _действие_, а уж потом -- **причастная** форма от этого _действия_.

Answer (score 0):

А какой уровень Олимпиады?

Я вообще не вижу причин выводить цепочку между этими словами, поскольку вряд ли одно образовалось от другого посредством третьего. Но если уж выводить, то без всяких недостающих звеньев.

По образцу: парковка<парковать; грунтовка<грунтовать. Ну какие тут еще цепочки нужны?

Или оба от "штриха" напрямую и пошли. Ибо вполне возможно образование слов на "-овка" напрямую от корневого морфа: бытовка<быт, винтовка<винт.

Так что Вы совершенно правы. 
Максимум: Штриховка<штриховать<штрих. Прилагательные и прочие слова тут совершенно излишни, они боковые ответвления, к словообразовательной цепочке не относятся. Может, в этом и был подвох вопроса?